# How and when to choose which objects to run collision tests on?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, architecture, objects

This might be problem with plenty of good solutions, but it's all not very clear to me, so I though I could ask and probably get some good hints. I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle interaction between objects in a platformer. Basically it's supposed to have two kinds of collision detection: one for solid objects that's based on line tests, and another to detect when ordinary objects touch.

These are some solutions that I know of, but they all have some serious problems:

- Store global references to the player and to solid objects, and have all other objects manually detect collisions with them.

  Good: trivial to implement, efficient

  Bad: limiting, since you can't easily have two non-player objects interact on collision; object implementations are strongly coupled to the player object's implementation
- Let objects ask for a list of objects of a certain type, and check for collisions in that list.

  Good: simple to use; useful for other things such as finding all solid objects

  Bad: I don't know how to implement it nicely (especially in a statically typed language); it requires use of inheritance to classify object types; objects in the same update priority interact slightly differently depending on which one updates first
- Let objects send and receive messages, and have a central collision detection system that runs after the update methods and sends messages to all colliding objects.

  Good: update order does not matter; object types need to know little, if anything, about each other

  Bad: must use the shapes provided by the collision system (no custom tests); most collision tests and messages will be wasted since collisions between most object types are ignored; a separate way to list all solid objects is still needed

So, any suggestions for improvements, alternatives, or good links to read? Suggestions that also simplify related problems like off-screen objects or objects positioned relative to other objects would be appreciated, too.

EDIT: To be clearer, I'm not asking about how to detect a collision given two objects, but about how the two objects can find out about each other in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use a spin on the first option you listed. When checking if A collides with B, however, a series of disqualifiers (or a singular disqualifier) can be used to reduce the computation required for each iteration of your collision checker. For example:

```
if((b.y >= a.y && b.y <= (a.y + a.h)) || ((b.y+b.h) >= a.y && (b.y+b.h) <= (a.y+a.h)))
{
  bool collide = checkCollision(a,b);
}
```

Obviously enough, if a collision-enabled object does not come within vertical range of another collision-enabled object, the collision system wont even both to run the numbers. There's tons of ways to implement this, too. If your system is texel based, you could even use raycasting as an accurate qualifier which might, in some cases, be simpler.

Comment: I know about using bounding boxes before a more expensive calculation, my main issue is about how A should find out about B's existence. Anyway, I like the first option's simplicity, but how how would you, for example, suggest implementing enemies that turn around when they touch each other? How should they find out about each other before doing collision tests?

Comment: Simply create a bounding box around the AI. This box should function just the same as the player's collision box, but it won't rely on any keyboard input (unless you want it to). Assuming you use a custom-made class for your AI enemies, you can also make sure that the two colliding units are both AI units, rather than AI hitting a wall and interacting the same way as when it hits another AI. If you want your AI to be more of a "unit", you could create a "squad" class with several AI as a private/protected value and some sort of squad-type functions to make the units act together.

Comment: That's still not really what I mean: checking whether the bounding boxes of any two objects intersect would be wasteful, since most classes of AI objects will never care about overlapping each other. So are there any good guides about how to organize the code so that bounding box tests are only done with objects that need to know about hitting each other, and ideally do so in a way that doesn't require modifying the "world" class every time a new kind of object behavior is added?